# Cant access public function? no member named?

Tags: c++

I am trying to access the function `getnoOfkids()` but even though its public I can't, why? I am only able to access the normal queue operations such as `size`,`emplace`, etc..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

class Family
{
private:
    int id, noOfElders, noOfKids;
public:
    bool operator ==(const  Family &f)
    {
        if ((this->id!= f.id) || (this->noOfElders != f.noOfElders)||(this->noOfKids != f.noOfKids))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    bool operator !=(const  Family &f)
    {
        return !(*this==f); //////////////////////
    }

    Family(int ide=0, int eld=0, int kid=0) {
        noOfElders = eld;
        noOfKids = kid;
        id = ide;
    }

    Family(const Family &a) {
        noOfKids = a.noOfKids;
        noOfElders = a.noOfElders;
        id = a.id;
    }

    Family operator=(Family const &a) {
        this->id = a.id;
        this->noOfElders = a.noOfElders;
        this->noOfKids = a.noOfKids;
        return *this;
    }

    int getnoOfkids() const  {
        return noOfKids;
    }

    int getnoOfElders() const {
        return noOfElders;
    }

    int getid() const {
        return id;
    }

    void setnoOfKids(int x) {
        noOfKids = x;
    }

    void setnoOfElders(int x) {
        noOfElders = x;
    }

    void setid(int x) {
        id = x;
    }

    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, const Family & a)
    {
        out << "The id of the travelers are: " << a.id << endl;
        out << "The number of elders are: " << a.noOfElders << endl;
        out << "The number of kids are: " << a.noOfKids << endl;
        return out;
    }

    friend istream &operator >> (istream &in, Family &a) {
        in >> a.id;
        in >> a.noOfElders;
        in >> a.noOfKids;
        return in;
    }
};

queue<Family> KidsQueue(queue<Family> &a, queue<Family> &b) {
    queue <Family> newA,newB;
    queue <Family> result;

    queue <Family> newA,newB; queue <Family> result;
    while(!a.empty()) 
    { if(a.getnoOfElders()) }
}
```

Comment: `getnoOfkids` is not used anywhere in your code. Please [edit] your question to include [mcve]. Please also copy and paste full error message (don't paraphrase it).

Comment: The type of `a` in `KidsQueue` is `queue<Family>`, not `Family`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `KidsQueue()`, your `a` parameter is an instance of [`std::queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) holding elements of type `Family`.  `a` itself is not a `Family`, so you can't call `Family` methods on it.  You need to access individual `Family` objects inside of the queue to call `Family` methods on them, eg:

```
while (!a.empty()) 
{
    if (a.front().getnoOfElders()) // <-- front() accesses the 1st Family object in the queue
    {
        ...
    }
    a.pop();
}
```

Comment: So functions like a->getnoOfElders() wont work since a is of type queue?

Comment: @Misu correct, because `std::queue` does not have an `operator->` defined

Comment: What about this case? i cant do result.push(a.pop()) ----while(!a.empty())
    { if(a.front().getnoOfElders()>3)
    result.push(a.pop())
    }

Comment: [`std::queue::pop()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/pop) returns a `void`, and `queue` itself does not support iteration without popping every element (besides, using a `while (!empty)` loop doesn't make sense unless every iteration of the loop modifies the `queue` so it can eventually become empty), so you need to use this instead: `while (!a.empty()) { if (a.front().getnoOfElders() > 3) { result.push(a.front()); } a.pop(); }` Otherwise, you have to iterate the underlying `queue.c` container directly instead.